# Error: This object does not have an attribute named "tag"

Tags: terraform

I'm attempting to import a datadog dashboard's json for a terraformed dashboard.

My dashboard with that json import:

```
module "test-dashboard" {
  source = "git::git@gitlab.com:company/data-services-for-company/terrabox.git//
modules/dynamic-datadog-dashboard?ref=tags/v2.1.13"
  
  title       = "test-dashboard"
  layout_type = "ordered"

    template_variables = [
    {
      name = "env"
      tag = "env"
    }
  ]

  template_variable_presets = {
      na = [
        {
          name = "Development"
          default = false
          variables = {
            env = ...
          }
        },
        {
          name = ...
       
        }
      ]
  }[var.location]


  widgets = [
    {
      template = "${path.module}/api-health.json"
    }
  ]

}
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
 Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on .terraform/modules/datadog_dashboard.test-dashboard/modules/dynamic-datadog-dashboard/main.tf line 250, in locals:
│  250:         {for x in lookup(template, "template_variables", []): x.name => x.tag}
│ 
│ This object does not have an attribute named "tag".
```

Which object is this looking at? I see the `tag` in `template_variables` so why is this failing?

the error is occuring in my private module in gitlab. How can I see what is erroring when that main.tf is just a terraform state configuration?

```
  ##########################
  ##  TEMPLATE VARIABLES  ##
  ##########################

  # Flatten out any templated variable configurations and override them with custom values if given
  template_variables = merge(merge([
    for template in local.templates:
        {for x in lookup(template, "template_variables", []): x.name => x.tag}
  ]...), {for x in var.template_variables: x.name => x.tag})
```

Looking further into that file locating the `local` and `templates`:

```
  ##  WIDGETS  ##
  ###############

  # Parse list of widgets if it is a string (possibly from varfile)
  raw_widgets = try(jsondecode(var.widgets), var.widgets)
  # Fill out and parse all templates in the list of widgets
  templates = {
    for widget in local.raw_widgets:
        index(local.raw_widgets, widget) => jsondecode(templatefile(
          try("${path.module}/presets/${widget["preset"]}.json", widget["template"]),
          lookup(widget, "context", {})
        ))
        if can(widget["preset"]) || can(widget["template"])
  }
```

Comment: This error is caused by the code in your private module, and so we cannot assist without more information about its contents.

Comment: That makes sense but when I look in that terraform state its just the configuration that it checks. Like for that line 250, see edited post.

Comment: Your added block helps, but not enough. It refers to a `local` called `templates`, and we still can't see how that is constructed.

Comment: Gotcha, found that and updated the post.

Comment: Thinking more about this, could it be the format of the json I'm attempting to import?